# Are there invariant sets for the covariance of the Kalman filter?

Tags: control-theory, parameter-estimation, kalman-filter

Consider the standard Kalman filter as in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Details). I'm interested in understanding how $\mathbf{P}_{k|k}$ evolves, when $\mathbf{F}_k, \mathbf{Q}_k, \mathbf{R}_k$ change in $k$. I wonder if $\mathbf{F}_k, \mathbf{Q}_k, \mathbf{R}_k$ are bounded for all $k$, and given $\mathbf{P}_{0|0}$, one can ensure $\mathbf{P}_{k|k}$ doesn't exit a bounded set $D\subset\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ (where $n\times n$ is the dimension of $\mathbf{P}_{k|k}$).

I have tried to search for results in this direction in books/articles without success, possibly since I don't exactly know how to call this property. I would call it "invariance", but whenever I search invariance along with the Kalman filter, I always get very different results with what I am looking for.

EDIT: just a technical comment. By invariant sets I mean, forward in time.

Comment: Maybe you can check the stability/convergence/asymptotic behavior of the Riccati difference equation, such as https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82299092.pdf

Comment: Interesting idea. thanks, I will check that.